# Why am I getting a 502 Bad Gateway error on my website after deleting cache Amazon S3 website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server

When I go to my website for the first time after deleting my cache I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

The expression the first impression is the most important comes to mind with this. Why is this happening and how do I stop it.

I read up and I have found that it is a server-side issue, I am using Amazon AWS's S3 bucket.

Is there any advice?

www.alexthemaverick.co.uk

Comment: is the resource public? what happens when you run the homepage by the long aws address? you might have to set that page as the homepage again

Comment: The resources are public. I have loaded in a different browser and didn't get the issue this time. Did you get the 502 error when you went to the page?

Comment: Loading ok for me here

Comment: Okay cool, I am in Germany at the moment, could this be the issue

Comment: Do you have a CDN in the middle? AWS is truly global... Germany or Australia or wherever shouldn't be an issue - probably you were too eager to refresh the page after replacing that file :) - AWS S3 has a disclaimer that replicating files between availability zones by s3 can have some lag... You probably got the short end of this stick

Comment: Okay, I am masking and forwarding my website with a godaddy domain, could it be through this?

Comment: Yup... most probably; I use cloudflare (for www.akberiqbal.com) which cache's the result and i have to flush its cache after every minor update...

Comment: Good advice I will give it a crack